# Azure SQL Connection through ADF having transient failure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

We have build ADF Pipeline where we have a step to connect to Azure SQL and run a query. So the ADF pipeline runs every single day and this step runs almost 98% of the time, but once in a while gets failed with the following error,

```
|ErrorCode=SqlFailedToConnect,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Database
```

Note : This issue gets resolved on restart.

We need a way to have this automated without manual intervention.

**We need to find if there is any way to retry if this fails the first time?**

Answer (score 1):

You can add a retry to any step you want.

Retry - is the number of times ADF will retry this step is it fails.

Retry Interval - the duration between retires (in seconds)

[image: retry]